# Java soundboard - sounds not portable

Tags: java, audio, jar, wav

I'm fairly new to Java. I've made a little sound board, but I just copied the portion that plays the .wav files. The apps works great on my own computer, but when I wrap it into a .jar and move it to another computer, the sounds don't play. I've read online that I need to use "getResourceAsStream", but I don't know how to implement that in my particular code.
Thanks

```
public void playShutup() {
        try {
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\coding\\IntelliJ Workspace\\SwearBall\\src\\sample\\shutUp.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let’s start with this:

```
new File("C:\\coding\\IntelliJ Workspace\\SwearBall\\src\\sample\\shutUp.wav")
```

Do the other computers have a file at that location?

If they don’t, then it shouldn’t surprise you that your program doesn’t work.  In fact, your program should have generated an exception which told you that the file was not found.

A .jar file is actually a zip file, with one or more Java-specific entries in it.  Since it is just a zip file, you can put whatever additional files you want in it, along with the compiled .class files which represent your program.  These additional files are known as *application resources* or sometimes just *resources.*

Entries within a zip file are not actual files, just subsequences of bytes within the zip file.  So, obviously, something that’s part of a zip file cannot be referenced with the File class, because, well, it’s not really a file.

Bundling resources with an application is a common practice.  So common, that the designers of Java thought it would be useful to include some easy methods for reading such resources.  You *could* use Java’s zip classes to look for it, but there’s a much easier way:  The [getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) and [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) methods of Class.

It is important to place a resource in a package-like directory.  So important, that the Class.getResource and Class.getResourceAsStream *expect it by default.*  Meaning, if you have a class named com.example.MyApplication, it will exist in your .jar as:

```
com/example/MyApplication.class
```

So, if you had a resource called `config.xml`, you would add it to your .jar as:

```
com/example/config.xml
```

This allows you write the following code:

```
URL configResource = MyApplication.class.getResource("config.xml");
```

Nice and clean, isn’t it?  In your case, you would be able to write:

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
    getClass().getResource("shutUp.wav"));
```

As for how to include shutUp.wav in your .jar file, that will depend on how you’re building your application.  Every IDE (like Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc.) expects a specific directory in your project (which may or may not currently exist) to contain resources that, when building, will be placed in the .jar.  Usually that directory is something like:

- src/resources
- src/main/resources

You should be able to find the resource directory by examining your project’s properties.

Remember, resources belong in a package, just like classes, so if your class were in the package `com.example`, you would place your resources in an identical tree:

- src/resources/com/example/shutUp.wav

or

- src/main/resources/com/example/shutUp.wav

If you’re building on the command line, just include your resources directory:

```
jar cf MyApplication.jar -C build/classes . -C src/resources .
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer. Much appreciated. 
I've moved the sound files into \src\resourses and changed the path in the code to "src\\resources\\kissMyButt.wav" rather than the specific drive, folder, etc. The app still works locally.

I'm not sure where to add the:
URL configResource = MyApplication.class.getResource("config.xml");
and
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
    getClass().getResource("shutUp.wav"));

I have methods called to play each sound when each button is pressed. This is all in the Controller class.